# generate table from entities on Eclipse

Tags: java

How to get a Platform that will able to generate DDL and 
how to configure Eclipse to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Generate DDL from *what*? Have a look at the [data tools platform](http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/downloads.php), this is a general "connector" for various databases. May provide a solution for your problem(s)